# Recoger datos formulario registro, procesarlos y enviar a API

Tags: php, api, formularios, symfony, prestashop

Estoy empezando a trabajar con prestashop y hay demasiadas cosas que aún no consigo hacer.

Estoy intentando recoger los datos que introduce el usuario cuando se registra (Formulario de registro estandard), mediante un módulo que se activa con el hook de registro(AcionCustomerAccountAdd) para posteriormente dar formato y enviar estos datos a una API externa, aprovechando el registro estandar de PrestaShop).

He probado bastantes maneras de hacerlo, pero parece que ninguna es la correcta. Cada vez que le doy a registro me salta HTTP ERROR 500 y no me recoge ningún dato (el registro normal de prestshop si que lo acaba procesando y me crea un usuario nuevo en la bbdd.

Actualmente tengo esta función en el módulo:

```
public function hookActionCustomerAccountAdd()
{
    $httpClient = HttpClient::create( ['auth_basic' => ['APIKEY', 'APIUSER '], 'headers' => [
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
        'Accept' => 'application/json'
    ]]);

    $mail = Tools::getValue('email');
    $firstname = Tools::getValue('firstname');
    $lastname = Tools::getValue('lastname');
    $cellphone = Tools::getValue('numero');
    $date = getdate();

    $data = array(
            "email"=>$mail,
            "date"=>$date,
            "firstname" =>$firstname,
            "lastname"=>$lastname,
            "lang"=> "es",
            "cellphone"=>$cellphone
);


    $data_json = json_encode($data);
```

La lógica que aplico es; conectarme a la API por HttpClient, recoger datos con los gets, ponerlos en un array y transformarlo json para enviarlo a la API posteriormente.
Pero creo que la lógica no es correcta.

Agradecería cualquier ayuda o orientación.

Comment: Lo que no esta claro es donde es que salta la respuesta con código 500, si en el API o en tu app, de ser en el API, seria bueno que consultaras que el formado del JSON que envías es el correcto.

Comment: Despues de seguir probando he visto que el error me lo está dando el httpclient por algún motivo, si se lo quito me pasa sin ningún problema. Puedo comprobar de alguna manera si el array se está rellenando? Un estilo alert o algo por el estilo que le pueda incrustar?

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Albert, no creo que sea tema de la API, ya que aún no le he llegado a pasar el json con $httpClient->request('POST.', 'API_URL');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitivamente he optado por utilizar cURL para realizar la conexión con la API y enviar los datos.
Por si a alguien le resulta de utilidad dejo el código:

```
$mail = Tools::getValue('email');
    $firstname = Tools::getValue('firstname');
    $lastname = Tools::getValue('lastname');
    $cellphone = Tools::getValue('cellphone');
    $date = getdate();

    $data = array(
        "email"=>$mail,
        "date"=>$date,
        "firstname" =>$firstname,
        "lastname"=>$lastname,
        "lang"=> "es",
        "cellphone"=>'+34'.$cellphone
    );


    $data_json = json_encode($data);



    $ch = curl_init('https://APIUSER:APIKEY@APIURL');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json);

    // Set HTTP Header for POST request
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_json))
    );

   // Submit the POST request
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

   // Close cURL session handle
    curl_close($ch);
```